# Stop child services when systemd socket connection closes

Tags: systemd, unix-sockets

I'm trying to launch a meta-service remotely through a socket. Requirements:

1. The socket should start the meta-service when a connection is established
2. The meta-service should start all child (`Wants=`) services upon start
3. When the connection is closed, the meta-service should stop
4. When the meta-service stops, it should stop all child (`ConsistsOf=`) services

I'm not expecting multiple connections, so my requirements are undefined if multiple connections are made.

Here's one attempt:

```
# simple.socket
[Unit]
Description=Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=11111
Accept=no

# simple.service
[Unit]
Description=Meta-service
Wants=simple-child.service # Will be a full tree of dependencies

[Service]
ExecStart=-cat -  # cat will fail to start because it doesn't accept connections
StandardInput=socket

# simple-child.service
[Unit]
Description=Child1
PartOf=simple.service # Puts a ConsistsOf= relationship in simple.service

[Service]
ExecStart=sleep infinity # Business goes here
```

The problem here is that when [`Accept=no`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html), the `ExecStart=` is responsible for handling the incoming connections.  `cat -` doesn't call [`accept()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) and so `simple.service` will fail to start. Is there another basic tool I could use in `ExecStart=` which would `accept()` the connections, but close when the a connection is stopped?  It could be the first or last connection, I'm agnostic to that.  That would be the easiest solution which also solves the rest of the question.  Is there an example of a C-application which uses `accept()` so I could figure out how systemd passes `sockfd` for our first argument `accept(int sockfd, ...)`?  Then I could write something myself.  I tried running [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzab6/xafunixsrv.htm), but I kept getting failures when using bind().

Here's another attempt using `Accept=yes`:

```
# simple.socket
[Unit]
Description=Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=11111
Accept=yes

# simple@.service  # Note the template here
[Unit]
Description=Meta-service
Wants=simple-child.service

[Service]
ExecStart=-cat - # now cat will work!
StandardInput=socket

# simple-child.service
[Unit]
Description=Child1
PartOf=simple@.service # This fails to connect to the instance

[Service]
ExecStart=sleep infinity # Business goes here
```

In this case, everything starts great.  When the connection is closed, `simple@XYZ.service` stops nicely, but `simple-child.service` keeps running.  That's because `PartOf=simple@.service` does not refer to the correct instance.  I'd REALLY prefer to avoid templating `simple-child.service`, but let's try it:

```
# simple.socket
[Unit]
Description=Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=11111
Accept=yes

# simple@.service
[Unit]
Description=Meta-service
Wants=simple-child@%i.service  % Starts simple-child as a template

[Service]
ExecStart=-cat -
StandardInput=socket

# simple-child@.service # Newly templated
[Unit]
Description=Child1
PartOf=simple@%i.service  # Using %i 

[Service]
ExecStart=sleep infinity # Business goes here
```

In this case `simple@.service` is templated as `simple@6-127.0.0.1:11111-127.0.0.1:49276.service`, but `%i` is only `6`. It spawns `simple-child@6.service` which is only `PartOf=simple@6.service` and so it fails to stop when `simple@6-127.0.0.1:11111-127.0.0.1:49276.service` stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, but it's in python which is not ideal for dependency reasons.

```
# simple.socket
[Unit]
Description=Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=11111
Accept=no

# simple.service
[Unit]
Description=Meta-service
Wants=simple-child.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/listen.py

# simple-child.service
[Unit]
Description=Child1
PartOf=simple.service

[Service]
ExecStart=sleep infinity
```

And the python script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from socketserver import TCPServer, StreamRequestHandler
import socket

class Handler(StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            c = self.rfile.read(1)
            if len(c) == 0:
                exit()

class Server(TCPServer):

    SYSTEMD_FIRST_SOCKET_FD = 3

    def __init__(self, server_address, handler_cls):
        TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler_cls, bind_and_activate=False)
        self.socket = socket.fromfd(self.SYSTEMD_FIRST_SOCKET_FD, self.address_family, self.socket_type)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "12.34.56.78", 12345 # This gets overridden by systemd
    server = Server((HOST, PORT), Handler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Now when the connection is established, `simple.service` and `simple-child.service` both launch.  When the connection is killed `simple.service` stops, but somehow `simple-child.service` doesn't stop despite the `PartOf=` relationship.  Adding `ExecStop=systemctl stop simple-child.service` to `simple.service` does work, but that's not a great solution.